# error: cannot convert ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘int’ in assignment

Tags: c++

im getting the above error for the following code. Please help me with what i am doing wrong.  This code has nested structures. For now it generates name for the generation structure based on the input given by the user.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;
using std::stringstream;
struct rootset {
  double totSize;
  const char *rStrtPtr;
  const char *rEndPtr;

  struct generations {
    double totSize;
    const char *genStrtPtr;
    const char *genEndPtr; 
    int numOfGen;
    int genName;

    struct object {
      double objSize;
      const char *objStrtPtr;
      const char *objEndPtr;
      string id;
      char markBit;
      char objPtr;


      struct freeList {
    double freeSpace;
    int flNumb; 
      };
    };
  } generation;
};

int main()
{

  int gen =0;
  cin >> gen;

  rootset* pRootSet = (rootset*)malloc(1200);

  for( i=0; i<gen; i++) {
    stringstream out;
    out << i;
   string s = out.str();
   string foo = "generation";

   pRootSet->generation.genName = foo.append(s);  /*Error is here*/
   cout<<"foo: "<<foo<<endl;
  }
}
```

i am trying to print this answer:

```
4
foo: generation0
foo: generation1
foo: generation2
foo: generation3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generation.genName is of INT type while you want to pass a string value without any conversion, that's why it gives it an error. Solution: do the conversion before.